# How to determine the basis of a (parametric) subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, given the subspace W defined as 
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
W = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\a-b&2b\end{bmatrix}\right\} \subseteq \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} M_{2,2} (\R) 
\end{align}
a, b being real numbers; 
how can the relative basis of W be determined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\a-b&2b\end{matrix}\right)=a\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)+b\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\-1&2\end{matrix}\right)$$
So, every vector in $W$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors
$$\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\-1&2\end{matrix}\right)\right\}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by relative basis? In general, $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^2$.

Do you mean a basis for the image of $W$, i.e., the column space? The basis in that case is simply the set of columns of $W$, i.e., $\{(a,a-b),(b,2b)\}$.